# selected option on drupal form not coming up first

Tags: forms

I added a '#default_value to my drupal7 form , and it says

```
<option selected="selected" value="81">Service</option>
```

(this is the option I want selected) but I want it to come out first in the list and it isnt .

how can I get it to come out first?

Comment: Sorry I just found out this is a firefox issue, not a drupal issue.  it only doesnt work in firefox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831848/firefox-ignores-option-selected-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a problem in firefox, and the way to fix it so it works in firefox as well is to add this: 
     $form['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';